# JavaScript Conflict with Canvas font element and Local Storage display

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a function that runs with windows onload to display a list of scores that are stored in local storage. Even if the list is empty it will display as it would when loading in a new browser.

```
function scoresListDisplay(){
storedEntries = [];
storedEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localstoragekey"));
highScoreList = game.querySelector("section#game ol.high-scores"); 
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  var st = storedEntries[i];                                   
  gamescorelist = document.createElement('li');
  gamescorelist.innerHTML = (typeof(st) != "undefined" ? st : "--" );
  highScoreList.appendChild(gamescorelist);
 }        
}
```

I also have other div tags such as one containing a canvas tag for the font of the page heading or title and other div tags which are used to display a countdown timer and current score.
The list above works fine but the thing is when the list is empty the canvas element with the title at the top of the page disappears and when the list is populated by one or more values (st) the canvas element reappears and is displayed as normal. All other div elements display ok.

I'm not sure but I think the problem may have something to do with the getItem return. Although the console reports this:

```
TypeError: storedEntries is null
```

Am I missing something within the function?

If anybody could help with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you see ...

```
storedEntries = [];
storedEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localstoragekey"));
```

You are redefining `storedEntries`, so the first line is useless. When localStorage is empty, `JSON.parse` will return null, and later you're accessing it as if it were an array.

Do it this way:

```
storedEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localstoragekey")) || [];
```

This means, *get the value of `JSON.parse` and, if it is not `null`, `0`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `false` or `''` initialise `storedEntries` with it; otherwise, initialise `storedEntries` with `[]`*.

Comment: `NaN` is falsey too :)